# Unable to access local scope of an asynch method from an inner function with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, closures

I'm having a problem with this small application. From my method "innerFunc", declared and executed once for each word in "self.words" I want to access the local scope of "outerFunc".

I need to access "item", which has to be different for each declaration of "innerFunc".

```
var self = this;
self.words = ["a", "b", "c"];

async.each(self.words,
          function outerFunc (item, callback) {
                var item = item;
                self.item = item;
                var innerFunc = function (error, response, body) {
                    console.log(self.words); //I can access to it.
                    console.log(self.item); //I can access it.
                    console.log(item); //Not accesible -> This is the problem
                    callback(null);
                };

                request("http://blablabla", innerFunc);

            },
          function(err){
            //Do nothing.
          }
        );
```

The thing is that I can access "self", a variable declared in global scope. But not "item" which is declared in local scope when declaring "innerFunc". How can I do it?

Also, If you know a better pattern to implement this chain of asynch tasks, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you define _"not accessible"_?

Comment: When you attempt to access `item`, do you get `undefined`? Does it error out? Is `self.item` the same as `item`?

Comment: @robertklep @Compynerd255 what chrome developer tool says is: `item: <not available>` And  `self.item` is "c" for all iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I solved my problem. It turns out that my solution was correct, although probably not the best example of how to structure code.

The thing is that to debug my code I'm using Node Inspector v0.12.3. It provides the same interface that WebKit Web Inspector.

When I was coding my app, in order to test my abilities about closures in a faster way I didn't fill my method with references to `item`. I stopped my debugger inside the function an I tried to use Watch Expression to see if `item` was visible.

My code was something like this:

```
...
var item = whatever; //Different value on each iteration.
myFunc = function(error, response, body) {
                console.log(self.words); 
                //stopping debugger and looking for "item" value using Watch Expression
 };
...
```

The output of Watch Expression was `item: <not available>`

When I changed to the correct method:

```
...
    var item = whatever; //Different value on each iteration.
    myFunc = function(error, response, body) {
                    console.log(self.words);
                    console.log(item);
                    //stopping debugger and looking for item using Watch Expression
     };
...
```

Now Watch Expression is giving me the proper value `item: whatever`.

It seems that WebKit Web Inspector (or Node Inspector) is not providing access to this kind of variables when you are not using them in a method, even if they should be accessible. It was a silly and triky problem at the same time.

If someone has a more precise explanation of why this is happening with this debugging tool, please share your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use a different function to return your wanted function in order to fixate a different "item" each time.
Try this code:

```
var self = this;
self.words = ["a", "b", "c"];

var retInnerFunc = function(item) {
        return function(error, response, body) {
                console.log(self.words);
                console.log(self.item);
                console.log(item); 
                callback(null);
            };
};


async.each(self.words,
      function outerFunc (item, callback) {
            var innerItem = item;
            self.item = item;

            request("http://blablabla", retInnerFunc(innerItem));

        },
      function(err){
        //Do nothing.
      }
    );
```

I also changed the name "item" for the inner var, I don't think it's the best naming, to use the same name as the argument...

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advice. But this is not what solved my error. I will publish another answer with the solution to my problem.